# Processing of sql query results in parts

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine

I have applications in PHP, Symfony.
I have a huge database. I would like to export the results of a query to a .csv file. Due to the size of the data, I can't keep it cached at one time. I need to take part of the results, add it to the file and take the next part.

I found solution in doctrine documentation.

```
$q = $this->_em->createQuery('select u from MyProject\Model\User u');
foreach ($q->toIterable() as $row) {
    // do stuff with the data in the row

    // detach from Doctrine, so that it can be Garbage-Collected immediately
    $this->_em->detach($row[0]);
}
```

It works perfect, but only for ORM query. I have large file (+300 lines) with raw sql. It has a lot of join, case etc. I cannot make it with inerrable, so it gets too much memory.

What can I do?

Comment: Search for the key word "cursor".

Comment: I tried to add offset and batchSize to my query and change it in loop. It's works, but it's very slow.

Comment: @janullo789 Can you add your offset/batchSize attempt to the question, possibly with a few words how you determined *it’s very slow* and what kind of performance you’re aiming for?